# Load heavy user control with laoding animation without freezing app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

so after more than a week of trying to solve it on my own I officially give up and turn to your help. Basically, it should not be so complicated so I have no idea why it does not work. I have a WPF app which contains a Main Window called surprise surpise...: Main_Window.
That window contain a user control called 'pageTransitionControl' that change its content according to what the client want to see. the 'pageTransitionControl' is there to support multiple animations and so on... Anyway, among all of the user controls,  i have a preety havy uc called ucBanks. before it shows, the ucBanks load a lot of data, manipulating it and display it on a very beautiful and smart charts. the problem is it takes some time to load it, approximately 6-7 seconds so i need the UI to show 'Loading' animation during that time (another user control called 'ucSpinner').
I'm Trying to load the ucBanks on a different thread to avoid freezing the application and it works great: the ucSpinner is showed immidiatlly and the ucBanks is loading on the background but when i change the content of the 'pageTransitionControl' i get this error:
"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".
I think i tried basically everything but i must missing somthing or doing somthing wrong.
This is where it all start, the btn_click event that load ucBanks:

```
ShowSpinner();
Thread.Sleep(100);
Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadUc));
newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newThread.IsBackground = true;
newThread.Start();
```

This is the ShowSpinner method:

```
private void ShowSpinner()
{
   ucSpinner.Opacity = 1;
}
```

and this is the LoadUc method:

```
private void LoadUc()
{
     ucOsh ucOshx = new ucOsh();
     Utils.LoadUc(ucOshx, null, PageTransitions.PageTransitionType.GrowAndFade, true, this, null, true);
}
```

With the LoadUc i called static class called 'Utils' holding the 'LoadUc' method:

```
public static void LoadUc(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl ucParent, System.Windows.Controls.UserControl ucChild, PageTransitions.PageTransitionType tranType, bool removeChildrens = true, System.Windows.Window w = null, List<Plist.Plist> lst = null, bool hideMenu = false)
        {
            MainWindow win = null;
            if (w != null) { win = (MainWindow)w; }
            else { win = (MainWindow)System.Windows.Window.GetWindow(ucChild); }
            win.Dispatcher.Invoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, (System.Action)delegate
            {
                win.pageTransitionControl.TransitionType = tranType;
                win.pageTransitionControl.PARAMS = lst;
                win.pageTransitionControl.Tag = ucParent.ToString();
                win.pageTransitionControl.pages.Push(ucParent);
                win.pageTransitionControl.Content = ucParent;  ----------->>>>This is where i get the error!!!
            });
        }
```

I understand that the main window is locked inside another thread but i cant see any other option to load it without freezing the entire app.
Does anyone have a suloution to my problem? SA :-) ?

What I have tried:

i tried working with background-worker, i chaned all of the settings of the dispatcher, loaded the user control inside and outside the threads...

Comment: Do NOT create your user control in another thread - it should be created on the UI thread like any other control and window. Rather, move all the heavy data loading and manipulating into separate methods/classes, and only let those methods be executed asynchronously/in a background thread. Also, since you are using WPF, you might want to look into MVVM, which should help you getting achieving a better separation of concerns...

Comment: thank you for your fast reply. I do know MVVM and work with it, but I do not think I explained myself well enough. Even if I do this the way you say, I still do not want to display the data, including the entire user control, until all data is processed and loaded. All this takes about 7 seconds and until then I want to display in the background an animation of loading. Is there a way to do this without freezing all UI?

Comment: Implement a property in your view model that indicates whether the data is loading or whether it is finished loading. You can trigger the display of the animation or the display of the control/view representing the data provided by view model based on the value of this property...

Comment: Use TPL or `async/await` approach, do not create threads by yourself if you do not understand what are you doing

Comment: Have you try to use a full screen spinner, and make it invisible when the ui operation it's done?

Comment: Guille89, You ask me exactly what I've been trying to do for over a week.